# general term for javascript built-in global object

Tags: javascript, object, built-in

Here is my code:

```
function convertStringToFunction(string) {
  var fn = String.prototype[string]; 
  // need to replace 'String' with something
  return (typeof fn) === 'function';  
}
convertStringToFunction('reduce'); // => false but need to return true
convertStringToFunction('toUpperCase') // => true
```

The goal is to search and call a built-in function with string of function name. 
However if string can take any function name like `reduce` and `toUpperCase`.
How can I ensure `fn` is always a function? in the other words, the previous function should always be true.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code, strings do not have a `reduce` function...

Comment: I want convertStringToFunction() to convert string to any built-in function as for as it exist. so I wonder if something like allBuiltinObjec.prototype exist.

Comment: Then why are you checking if the function name is a property of `String.prototype` ?

Comment: Global names are `window[string]`. But there's no global `reduce` function, it's a property of `Array.prototype`.

Comment: There's also no global `toUpperCase` function, it's only a property of `String.prototype`. There's no single place that you can look for the properties of all built-in prototypes.

Comment: @Barmar, thank you. Understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* this is what you want:

```
// this is currently the *only* certain way to get a
// reference to the global object
var global = new Function('return this;')();

// this is dicey, see note below
var isNative = function(fn) {
  return fn.toString().match(/native code/i);
};

// this will return a true if the passed in name is a built-in
// function of any of the global constructors or namespace objects
// like Math and JSON or the global object itself.
var isBuiltInFunction = function(name) {
  var tests = [
    global,
    String,
    Function,
    RegExp,
    Boolean,
    Number,
    Object,
    Array,
    Math,
    JSON
  ];

  // test for native Promises
  if (typeof Promise === 'function' && isNative(Promise)) {
    tests.push(Promise);
  }

  // test for document
  if (typeof document !== undefined) {
    tests.push(document);
  }

  // test for Symbol
  if (typeof Symbol === 'function' && isNative(Symbol)) {
    tests.push(Symbol);
  }

  return tests.some(function(obj) {
    return typeof obj[name] === 'function' && isNative(obj[name]);
  });
};
```

Note that the `Function.prototype.toString` is implementation-dependent, this may not work on all platforms. You can omit it, but then it will count user-defined versions of these as 'built-in'.

Comment: I think there is some bug in your code. But I understand what you mean now. Thanks.